# git show only remote branches

Tags: git, git-log

how can I show branches by date on server?
On [this page](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2345/show-git-branches-by-date-useful-for-showing-active-branches) I have following query found:

```
for k in `git branch|perl -pe s/^..//`;do echo -e `git show --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%ci %Cblue%cr%Creset" $k|head -n 1`\\t$k;done|sort –r
```

With git branch -rv I can see the branches on the server, but no additional information.

How could you build such a thing, but only for the server, ie. Show all branches, which are located only on the server?

Unfortunately, I am familiar with the console not good enough to make it rebuild itself :-(

Answer (score 1):

`git branch` has a `--sort` option.

So you can do:

`git branch -r --sort=authordate`

To show only remote branches sorted by the author date. Use `committerdate` for the commit date.

To reverse the order, add `-` to the sort field:

`git branch -r --sort=-authordate`

---

See this link https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref under "FIELD NAMES" for the possible keys you can pass to `--sort` in `git branch`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for is `git-for-each-ref`

For your particular requirement it would be something like this:

`git for-each-ref --sort=-authordate --format='%(authordate:short) %(refname)' refs/heads refs/remotes`

This will print your remote branches orderderd by author date

Hope it helps